# Why isn't data transfered in my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

Hey, I'm working on a helpdesk in MVC2, and I'm having a problem with data not being transferred from my views through my ViewModels.

On the home page, I have three DropDownLists where you can choose a problem area from. You can then push a button to either report a problem or go to the FAQ. If you choose a problem area in the DropDownLists, the site should remember what you chose by having the data transfer with the viewmodel.

But when I get to the Post method for home Index, my SelectLists and SelectListItems are null, whereas the string for containing the button info contains the correct data.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my home controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel()
        {
            // The lists with problem areas are populated.
            problemAreas1 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"),
            problemAreas2 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"),
            problemAreas3 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName")
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HomeIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // snip
    }
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    // A SelectList containing elements for the DropDownLists in the Home "Index" view.
    public SelectList problemAreas1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList problemAreas2 { get; set; }
    public SelectList problemAreas3 { get; set; }

    // Items chosen in the DropDownLists.
    public SelectListItem itemOne { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem itemTwo { get; set; }
    public SelectListItem itemThree { get; set; }

    // String for IDing what button is pressed.
    public string submitButton { get; set; }
}
```

And my home index view (which inherits from HomeIndexViewModel, I just didn't include the code because it screws up the post):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {%>
<h2>
    Search for your problem:</h2>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Width="300px">
Choose a problem area, and search for an answer to your problem in the FAQ, 
    or you can press the report button to report your problem.</asp:Label>
<%-- Here are the DropDownLists. --%>
<p style="width: 220px; height: 24px;">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.itemOne, Model.problemAreas1, "Choose a problem area")%>
</p>
<p style="width: 220px;">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.itemTwo, Model.problemAreas2, "Choose a problem area")%>
</p>
<p style="width: 220px">
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.itemThree, Model.problemAreas3, "Choose a problem area")%>
</p>
<p>
    <%-- Here are the two buttons allowing people to do a search or create a new ticket respectively. --%>
    <input type="submit" value="Search for problems" name="submitButton" id="searchButton" />
    <input type="submit" value="Report problem" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" />
</p>
<%} %>
```

Thank you for your time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit your form back to the POST action it is perfectly normal that the problemAreas1,2,3 properties will be null because their contents is never posted. You will need to repopulate them the same way you did in your GET action. As far as the itemOne,Two,Three properties are concerned they should be simple string values and not of type  `SelectListItem`.

Model:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    // A SelectList containing elements for the DropDownLists in the Home "Index" view.
    public SelectList problemAreas1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList problemAreas2 { get; set; }
    public SelectList problemAreas3 { get; set; }

    // Items chosen in the DropDownLists.
    public string itemOne { get; set; }
    public string itemTwo { get; set; }
    public string itemThree { get; set; }

    // String for IDing what button is pressed.
    public string submitButton { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel()
    {
        // The lists with problem areas are populated.
        problemAreas1 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"),
        problemAreas2 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"),
        problemAreas3 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName")
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

//
// POST: /Home/

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeIndexViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model wasn't valid =>
        // show the same form so that the user can fix validation errors
        viewModel.problemAreas1 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName");
        viewModel.problemAreas2 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName");
        viewModel.problemAreas3 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName");
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    // TODO: everything went fine => update your database and redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I missed.  String values, Int Values, Guid Values, or any one of the Value types.

Comment: That's how I had it before I changed my DropDownLists to DropDownListFor. When I use strings and press the button to search the FAQ (the setup for the lists is the same as with my home Index view) I get this exception: 
The ViewData item that has the key 'itemOne' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. 

Which is why I changed them to SelectListItems in the first place.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I wasn't populating my DropDownLists in the FAQ controller. Thanks for the help, it's working now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the page directive on your view that let's it know about your model?

Something like this should be the first line of your view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomeIndexViewModel>" %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to add it in the code section, but it screwed up the post so I left it out. I forgot to add the info before I posted it though, and made an edit 30 seconds later. I have it in there though. :) But thanks. :)

Comment: when you debug does your viewModel actually contain the objects it is suppose too?  Your code looks fine so maybe your model is empty.

Comment: Yeah, when I debug and open the viewmodel up, everything is there. But "submitButton" is the only one that isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

Your select lists will be null because that data is not passed back in the form, which should be ok.  However, because they are null there is no `SelectListItem` MVC can find in the collection to return, so it is also null.

Try adding the following to your constructor of `HomeIndexViewModel` instead of in the controller (just to see what happens)

```
problemAreas1 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"), 
problemAreas2 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName"), 
problemAreas3 = new SelectList(helpDeskRepository.GetProblemAreas(), "ProblemAreaID", "ProblemAreaName")
```

What I believe will happen on the return POST the binder will create your HomeIndexViewModel with the SelectLists populated and should be able to populate your `SelectListItem`.

Something seems a bit fishy though. My gut instinct is telling me that the `SelectListItem` shouldn't be null though.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and my SelectLists are populated as they should, but my SelectListItems are still null. Also, when I push one of the buttons now, I get a MissingMethodException saying there is no constructor without parameters for this object, where before the code would stop because it got a null input from the SelectListItems.

Comment: It sounds like you added a constructor to the controller instead of the `HomeIndexViewModel` or the constructor for the `HomeIndexViewModel` is not parameterless, which it should be.

Comment: Would you also be so kinda as you to update your question with the  output for one of the HTML Select elements?